# How did the barnacles get there in Pirates of the Carribean: Dead Men Tell No Tales?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

In *Dead Men Tell No Tale*, Will Turner appears to have a nightmare about being visited by a cursed Davy Jones during the post-credits scene. But there are still barnacles on the floor after Turner "wakes up". How can this be considering

> not only did Turner kill Davy Jones in *At World's End* but the destruction of Poseidon's Trident broke all curses upon the sea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though Trident of Poseidon broke all the curse, the return of Davy Jones is still a plot hole. This end credit sequence can be a setup for the sixth film and given that Disney is counting on another sequel, this appears to be true.

This possible plot-hole might be explained in the sixth film and Davy Jones might be main antagonist in it. Till then, this is pure speculation and nothing else.

From [an interview of director Joachim Rønning given to Cinema Blend](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1631090/is-pirates-of-the-caribbean-5-really-the-end-heres-what-the-co-director-says)

> It's difficult to ever know. **I think that there's always... this is the beginning of the finale.** [laughs] It depends on how you look at it. But I never take anything for granted, and I love the franchise. These kinds of movies, they remind me of the kind of movies I grew up with, those kind of adventure movies that made me want to become a filmmaker. So for me to be able to be a part of this and direct a Pirates of the Caribbean is a dream come true. But I don't know if it's the last one, or if they'll make another ten of them -- I don't know! But I hope so!

Producer Jerry Bruckheimer also [hinted for sixth movie](http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/pirates-of-the-caribbean/news/a829179/pirates-of-the-caribbean-franchise-johnny-depp-will-return/).